# How to extract the First IP Address from 'X-Forwarded-For' using Log Insight Query?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

How do I extract the first IP address from the following: `X-Forwarded-For":"1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2`?

I am currently using the following query:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /Endpoint request body after transformations/
| parse @message "X-Forwarded-For\":\"*\"" as @IP
| stats count(*) by @IP
| limit 20
```

However, when I run the query, I get results like this:

```
1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.4
1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.5
1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.6
```

What changes do I need to make in my query to only extract the first IP address?

Comment: `limit 1` ?______________

Comment: The limit 20 is just to limit the results the query returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have more than one ip, separated by commas, you can just terminate the parsing at `,` instead of `\"`, like this:

```
| parse @message "X-Forwarded-For\":\"*," as @IP
```

If you can also have just 1 ip, without the comma at the end, then you can do something like this:

```
| parse @message /X-Forwarded-For\":\"(?<@IP>.*?)[,\"]/
```

This will take everything up to the first comma or the end quote, if the comma is not there.